# Polymer conflict with double curly braces

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

gives a method to change double curly braces expression in polymer ?

i will use polymer data binding and tornados jinja2 template engine booth.

In angular i can do:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces are hardcoded and can't be changed to something else https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/718